# replacing a string using button vba

Tags: vba

Edited:

I'm more on PHP and I just started learning VBA.
This is the code that I made for the button.

```
Private Sub btnConvert_Click()

Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim d As String
Dim e As String
Dim f As String


a = "a"
b = "b"
c = "c"
d = "d"
e = "e"
f = "f"
Columns("B").Replace what:=a, replacement:=b, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
Columns("B").Replace what:=c, replacement:=d, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
Columns("B").Replace what:=e, replacement:=f, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
End Sub
```

Now, my problem is:
Just like in the code above, it happens that "b" will be replaced with "a".
But now I also want to remove a part of a string.

For example the strings are:

```
 a(hey)/(qworty);
 c(yow)/(asdf);
 e(wow)/(zxcv_786);
```

When I click the button the text should be replaced as:

```
b(hey); 
c(yow);
e(wow);
```

Hope you understood.
Thanks.

Comment: `Columns("B").Replace what:="/(qworty)", replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False`

Comment: I changed the examples. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

you could try this:

```
Private Sub btnConvert_Click()

    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    Dim c As String
    Dim d As String
    Dim e As String
    Dim f As String


    a = "a"
    b = "b"
    c = "c"
    d = "d"
    e = "e"
    f = "f"

    With columns("B")
        .Replace what:="/*;", Replacement:=";", lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
        .Replace what:=a & "(", Replacement:=b & "(", lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
        .Replace what:=c & "(", Replacement:=d & "(", lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
        .Replace what:=e & "(", Replacement:=f & "(", lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @akamariaclaraaa, did you get through it?

Comment: @akamariaclaraaa, any chance to get feedback from you?

Answer (score 0):

Although you could run a find and replace using RegEx (there are plenty of examples on this site) you could also loop over your range, create and array by splitting the string at the "/" and writing the first element of the array back to the cell.

```
Private Sub btnConvert_Click()
Dim c As Range
Dim arr() As String

    'Loop Column B. Change This If It Doesn't Exactly Meet Your Requirements
    For Each c In Range("B:B")
        'Exit When We Get To An Empty Cell. Again This May Need To Be Changed Depending On Requirements
        If Len(c) = 0 Then Exit For
        'Create An Array
        arr() = Split(c, "/")
        'Write The First Element Back
        c = arr(0)
    Next c

End Sub
```